# html/css: how to on a single line center "title" and have on right buttons

Tags: html, css

Here is the html that I have:

```
<div id="top">
    <span id="title">Some Title</span>
    <span id="buttons"><button>Bla</button><button>Foo</button></span>
</div>
```

What CSS to use to center `#title` and to have `#buttons` on the right side?

Comment: As per the two responses (as of the time of this writing) it would be useful to clarify if you want the title simply centered within "top" (right in the middle, no matter what buttons are there) or if you want it centered in the space leftover after potentially adding buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `#title` to `display:block; margin:auto;`

Set `#top` to `position:relative;` or `position:absolute;`

Set `#buttons` to `position:absolute; top:0; right:0;`

Comment: Absolute positioning on two different elements is a poor solution to something that can be achieved using floating.

Comment: Floating doesn't remove the buttons from the document flow, causing it to conflict with his desire to center to title.  What is your solution?

Comment: @minitech positioning and floating are both equally good solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This can be the css for your problem. Check this out.

```
#top
{
  text-align:center;
}

#buttons
{
float:right;
}
```

Comment: As per Jack's comment in his response: this does not center the title within #top, but rather within the space of #top's width minus the width taken up by #buttons.